# How do I correctly add a variable to a array?

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, error-handling

I am trying to assign a variable to an array but I keep getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error and I am stumped on why it doesn't work.

THE QUESTION:
    Write a program that reads an arbitrary number of integers that are     in the range 0 to 50 inclusive and counts how many occurrences of each are entered. Indicate the end of the input by a value outside of the range. After all input has been processed., print all of the values (with the number of occurrences) that were entered one or more time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IntCounter {
public static void main (String[]args) {

//variables 
int i = 0;
final int MaxValue = 51;

int userInput[]=new int[i]; //Initializing array to store user unput
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //Initializing scanner




   for(i=0; i<MaxValue; i++) {

        System.out.println("please enter a number" + "between 0 and      50, or greater then 50 to finish"");
        int u = scan.nextInt();

        if (u<MaxValue) {
        userInput[i]=u; //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
        }

    }



 //outputs array values after typing a value out of range
    for(int o=0; o<=i; o++,i++) {
        System.out.println("Your values are:" + userInput[i]);


    }
```

}}

```
OUTPUT:
please enter a number
4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:       Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
 at IntCounter.main(IntCounter.java:21)
```

Comment: Array length is immutable after initialization. You are initializing Your array with I which has value 0, so Your array has length = 0. Initialize it with int userInput[]=new int[MaxValue]

Comment: The answer to the question as you asked it is that you're creating an array of size 0 and then trying to put stuff in it (int userInput[] = new int[i], where "i" is 0). Obviously you can't do that, hence the error. That said, you appear to have a misunderstanding about what the goal of this question is. I'm assuming this is a homework problem, so I'm not going to give you the answer straight up. I can say with certainty that you don't need to store every input integer. Think about how you could solve this problem without doing that.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;

int userInput[]=new int[i]; // here you are creating an array of length 0. so you can not assign any value in it.


int userInput[]=new int[MaxValue];// I think you mean this while creating array.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
final int MaxValue = 51;

int userInput[]=new int[i];
```

Here you initialize `userInput` to `0`, perhaps you mean to do:

```
int userInput[]=new int[MaxValue];
```

Which will declare the array to be of size `51`.

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs whenever you try to access a position in the array larger than the array size.

Clearly a size of `0` will not be able to contain any elements, thus always throwing the `Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the array of size i as follows

```
int userInput[]=new int[i]
```

However value of is 0
Hence it is creating an array of size 0 thus causing a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: The arbitray number of inputs does not actually have anything to do with the array in this case with the way he has it set up (he does not need `ArrayList`).  All he needs to do it add `1` each time that number comes up in the array.  For example if they type `34`, position 34 in the array is now `1`.  Type it again, it is now `2`.  Then after the loop you can print all the positions that are 1 or above.  This is still arbitrary length of input while using an array.